# Image content slider with text div slider jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a content slider like lightslider. Now I want to have text div which will be change with the images. PLease suggest me a jquery if there is any.

[Lightslider](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightslider/)

I want to have the effect like [My project link](http://krazzywebz.com/susomoy/urna/women-black-kurta/). I installed flexslider but the text div should be separate. I need it responsive.

Pls help me to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This plugin scrolls each container `Li`

So if you want to place any kinds of text to scroll with the image

use following code

```
<li> <img>item image here />
<span> your Text Block here with styles </li>
<li> <img>item image here />
<span> your Text Block here with styles </li>
<li> <img>item image here />
<span> your Text Block here with styles </li>
```